# Discovering services with ZeroMQ

Tags: c, algorithm, networking, zeromq

Suppose one's got more than two (ideally, lots of) servers. Some of them provide, for example, http or ftp service. Only *some of them*. There is one 'client' computer which needs to gather information from every http server but it doesn't 'know' which servers are http ones. The client program is written in C using ZeroMQ. How does it find out which servers are the needed ones?

I would appreciate it if you provide me with some code examples. Thank you!

Comment: @dmg, http server is just example. Only the client's written using ZeroMQ

Comment: Unless I am missing something, ZeroMQ and discovery are orthogonal. For discovery, you need something like Bonjour (avahi, zeroconf, whatever). As a last resort you me port scan your servers, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

if it's all inside a local network you can use czmq [zbeacon](http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:zbeacon).

If it is in the cloud you can use czmq [zgossip](http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:zgossip).

If it cross LAN application I suggest doing centralized configuration, have zeromq application that is well known to all http servers. Each http server need to register with the centralized server.

Comment: Anyone got any links to a sample project doing discovery with CZMQ zbeacon, preferably in C or Rust?